# Django url handling?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

After decoupling url file to our app we are facing problem:

Example:

http://www.oursite.com/ourprefix/xyz/wsz

1. How to handle urls in template ( to accomodate for any prefix(ourprefix) in url)
2. How to do HttpResponseRedirect without hard-coded urls (also outprefix problem is present here)

Comment: What do you mean by "handle" urls in template? Just put them in an anchor's href attribute...

Comment: Can you be more specific. What do you have to do with the prefix? This should just be an easy regex in the urls.py

Comment: Could you be more specific in your question ? seems like you're adding a language prefix in your urls.

Answer (score 3):

Use [named urls](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url) in `urls.py`.

1. Use the [`{% url name %}`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url) template tag. It will insert the correct path.
2. Use [`reverse('name', **kwargs)`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#reverse) for the redirect.

an example:

in proj/urls.py:

```
patterns = patterns('',
   (r'^prefix/', include('proj.app.urls') ),
)
```

in proj/app/urls.py:

```
patterns = patterns('',
    url(r'object/^(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/', edit_object_view, name="edit"),
)
```

in proj/app/views.py:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:edit', {'pk':pk}))
```

in proj/app/templates/app/my_template.py:

```
<a href="{% url app:edit pk=pk %}"> <!-- generates /prefix/object/123/edit/ -->
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want to resolve a particular view to a URL inside the template?

You should use the url-reverse method in Django. See [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#topics-http-reversing-url-namespaces).

1) For the template, you can use:

```
<a href="/path/to/{{prefix}}/xyz"> Link </a>
```

Where the "prefix" is a variable set in your Context that you pass to the template. You can also dynamically pick the right URL:

```
{% url application.views.viewfunc parameter1 parameter2 %}
```

See [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url) for more details.

2) So to HttpResponseRedirect, you can do:

```
HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(your_view_function))
```

It also accepts parameters.

Comment: Do I have to put {{prefix}} on my own or there is some kinda of system that will do that for me? Is application somehow aware of that prefix auto-magically.

Comment: You don't say how you are serving from that prefix, but assuming you've just done it via setting the WSGI alias, then Django automatically knows it.